# How to implement AlertDialog. password is not enter in edit text?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have  implemented activity with edittext and button:

After user entered a password and clicked a button, I'd like to verify the password and if it is correct open another activity. If the password is wrong I'd like to display an error message using AlertDialog.

Is it possible? How?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enter);


    //---load the SharedPreferences object---
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String a = prefs.getString(PASSWORD, "pa");
    System.out.println("saved Password" +a);    

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName); 
    String theText = et.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("entered Password"+theText); 

    //---get the SharedPreferences object---
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PASSWORD, theText );

    //---save the values---
    editor.commit(); 


    Button data = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Ok);            
    data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Enter.this,Data.class);                
            startActivity(i);                   
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Please post some Java code here because the xml you posted and the description of your problem is to confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the password string into button click event.There,you can open a dialog depending on the correction of password.

Like:

```
EditText txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
Button login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{

       public void onClick()
       {
           String password=txtName.getText().toString().trim();
          //verify the password and save result to boolean matching;
          if(matching)
               //open other activity
          else
          {
            AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alt_bld.setMessage("Password is invalid!")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                         dialog.cancel();
                      }
               })
         });
         AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
         // Title for AlertDialog
         alert.setTitle("Title");
         // Icon for AlertDialog
         alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
         alert.show();
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move code into the onClickListener on your button:

```
Button data = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Ok);            
data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName); 
        String theText = et.getText().toString();
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (theText.equals(prefs.getString("PASSWORD")))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Enter.this,Data.class);                
            startActivity(i);       
        }
        else
        {
            showDialog(myDialogID);
        }            
    }   
});
```

Then of course you need to implement the AlertDialog. `myDialogID` should be an unique integer. (Only relevant if you use more Dialogs). See the [android dev guide for Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
  case 0:
  return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
         .setTitle(“This is a dialog with some simple text...”)
         .setPositiveButton(“OK”, new
          DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton)
       {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
           “OK clicked!”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 })
         .setNegativeButton(“Cancel”, new
          DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton)
      {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            “Cancel clicked!”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 })
```